# Change ion-refresher & ion-infinite-scroll color

Tags: css, ionic-framework, colors, customization, ion-infinite-scroll

It's a "simple" request but I'm not able to achieve this result...
In my app I have these two components:

```
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content 
      pullingIcon="ios-arrow-down-outline"
      pullingText="Scorri per aggiornare"
      refreshingSpinner="circles"
      refreshingText="Aggiornamento...">>
    </ion-refresher-content>
  </ion-refresher>
```

and

```
<ion-infinite-scroll [enabled]="morePagesAvailable" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
    loadingSpinner="bubbles"
    loadingText="Caricando più post ...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

And they works fine with a white background. Now I need to change the background color to black but now the text of the two components it's not visible anymore because it's black by default. 
How can I change che color of the two components?

I tried with a CSS class but the color it's not applied. 
How is it possible to customize these components?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v1/api/directive/ionRefresher/) suggest (at least for version 1 of ionic):

> The ionSpinner icon to display after user lets go of the refresher.
>   The SVG ionSpinner is now the default, replacing rotating font icons.
>   Set to none to disable both the spinner and the icon.

Closes thing in SVG to `color` is `fill` property. so you may use it instead of `color`.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

HTML Code

```
  <ion-infinite-scroll threshold="100px" (ionInfinite)="loadData($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content class="loadingspinner"
      loadingSpinner="crescent"
      loadingText="Loading...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

Respective CSS

```
.loadingspinner{
    --color : #adadad;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]

```
.spinner-crescent{
    color: #adadad;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Hi @DonaldDuck, I have explained the fix in the answer. feel free to ask if any queries. I will be happy to explain :)

Answer (score -1):

If this helps someone. You have to add a class to the infinite scroll content or just use the tag selector.

```
<ion-infinite-scroll [enabled]="morePagesAvailable" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content
        class="infinite-scroll-color"
        loadingSpinner="bubbles"
        loadingText="Caricando più post ...">
    </ion-infinite-scroll-content>
</ion-infinite-scroll>
```

And then change the stroke property of the tag line, to change the spinner svg color.

```
.infinite-scroll-color {
    line {
        stroke: #YOURCOLOR;
    }

    //If you want to change the text color too, just add this css
    .infinite-loading-text {
        color: #YOURCOLOR;
    }
}
```

Cheers!